# How to update a Static Dataframe with Streaming Dataframe in Spark structured streaming

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I have a Static `DataFrame` with millions of rows as follows.

Static `DataFrame` :

```
--------------
id|time_stamp|
--------------
|1|1540527851|
|2|1540525602|
|3|1530529187|
|4|1520529185|
|5|1510529182|
|6|1578945709|
--------------
```

Now in every batch, a Streaming `DataFrame` is being formed which contains id and updated time_stamp after some operations like below.

In first Batch :

```
--------------
id|time_stamp|
--------------
|1|1540527888|
|2|1540525999|
|3|1530529784|
--------------
```

Now in every batch, I want to update the Static DataFrame with the updated values of Streaming Dataframe like follows. **How to do that?**

Static DF after first batch :

```
--------------
id|time_stamp|
--------------
|1|1540527888|
|2|1540525999|
|3|1530529784|
|4|1520529185|
|5|1510529182|
|6|1578945709|
--------------
```

I've already tried **except(), union() or 'left_anti' join**. But it seems **structured streaming doesn't support such operations**.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, not only structured streaming but also most of streaming frameworks, when stream and static table join happens state table is used as just a lookup table, not a thing to insert/update. Stream will the main data source to read and update in that case. So you may need some tricks (not sure if any) other than structured streaming.

Comment: Hi @JungtaekLim . Thanks for replying. This is a peculiar case where I have to update the Static dataframe as it is being used in other parts with the streaming dataframe.

Comment: Hello @Swarup, did you find any way to do this?

Comment: Hello @Allan, if you're using Spark version > 2.4.0, you just simply need to call foreachBatch((batch: DataFrame, batchId: Long) on your dataframe writestream. However, I still don't know how to do this on older version of Spark. But why wouldn't you take advantage of newer versions anyway right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I resolved this issue by Spark 2.4.0 AddBatch method which coverts the streaming Dataframe into mini Batch Dataframes. But for the <2.4.0 version it's still a headache.

Comment: could you explain more for the AddBatch method to overcome this problem? could you share some code of implement this? I am encountering the same problem now.

Comment: Hey @Hong. Kompe has already explained the process in the comment above.

Answer (score 1):

As already explained by Swarup himself, you can use the forEachBatch output sink if you use Spark 2.4.x.

The sink takes a function `(batchDF: DataFrame, batchId: Long) => Unit` where batchDF is the currently processed batch of the streaming dataframe and this can be used as a static Dataframe. 
So in this function you are able to update the other dataframe with the values of each batch.

See sample below:
Assuming you have a dataframe named `frameToBeUpdated` with the same schema as for example an instance variable and you want to keep your state there

```
df
  .writeStream
  .outputMode("append")
  .foreachBatch((batch: DataFrame, batchId: Long) => {
   //batch is a static dataframe

      //take all rows from the original frames that aren't in batch and 
      //union them with the batch, then reassign to the
      //dataframe you want to keep
      frameToBeUpdated = batch.union(frameToBeUpdated.join(batch, Seq("id"), "left_anti"))
    })
    .start()
```

Updating logic is from: [spark: merge two dataframes, if ID duplicated in two dataframes, the row in df1 overwrites the row in df2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57838825/spark-merge-two-dataframes-if-id-duplicated-in-two-dataframes-the-row-in-df1)

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar issue. Below is my foreachBatch that i have applied for updating static dataframe. I would like to know how to return the updated df that is done in foreachBatch.

```
def update_reference_df(df, static_df):
    query: StreamingQuery = df \
        .writeStream \
        .outputMode("append") \
        .format("memory") \
        .foreachBatch(lambda batch_df, batchId: update_static_df(batch_df, static_df)) \
        .start()
    return query

def update_static_df(batch_df, static_df):
    df1: DataFrame = static_df.union(batch_df.join(static_df,
                                                 (batch_df.SITE == static_df.SITE)
                                                 "left_anti"))

    return df1
```