# spark: merge two dataframes, if ID duplicated in two dataframes, the row in df1 overwrites the row in df2

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

There are two dataframes: df1, and df2 with the same schema. ID is the primary key.

I need merge the two df1, and df2. This can be done by `union` except one special requirement: if there are duplicates rows with the same ID in df1 and df2. I need keep the one in df1.

df1:

```
ID col1 col2
1  AA   2019
2  B    2018
```

df2:

```
ID col1 col2
1  A    2019
3  C    2017
```

I need the following output:

df1:

```
ID col1 col2
1  AA   2019
2  B    2018
3  C    2017
```

How to do this? Thanks. I think it is possible to register two tmp tables, do full joins and use `coalesce`. but I do not prefer this way, because there are about 40 columns, in fact, instead of 3 in the above example.

Comment: can you show some sample input and the expected output?

Answer (score 6):

Given that the two DataFrames have the same schema, you could simply union `df1` with the `left_anti` join of `df2` & `df1`:

```
df1.union(df2.join(df1, Seq("ID"), "left_anti")).show
// +---+---+----+
// | ID|co1|col2|
// +---+---+----+
// |  1| AA|2019|
// |  2|  B|2018|
// |  3|  C|2017|
// +---+---+----+
```

Comment: very nice and concise solution.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is, `union`ing the dataframes with an identifier column that specifies the dataframe and use it thereafter for prioritizing row from `df1` with a function like `row_number`.

PySpark SQL solution shown here.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit,row_number,when
from pyspark.sql import Window
df1_with_identifier = df1.withColumn('identifier',lit('df1'))
df2_with_identifier = df2.withColumn('identifier',lit('df2'))
merged_df = df1_with_identifier.union(df2_with_identifier)
#Define the Window with the desired ordering
w = Window.partitionBy(merged_df.id).orderBy(when(merged_df.identifier == 'df1',1).otherwise(2))
result = merged_df.withColumn('rownum',row_number().over(w))
result.select(result.rownum == 1).show()
```

A solution with a `left join` on `df1` could be a lot simpler, except that you have to write multiple `coalesce`s.