# Update Static Dataframe with Streaming Dataframe in Spark structured streaming

Tags: spark-streaming

I have a similar use case as per post [How to update a Static Dataframe with Streaming Dataframe in Spark structured streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53004818/how-to-update-a-static-dataframe-with-streaming-dataframe-in-spark-structured-st/62975798#62975798). You can take the same data as example from the said post.

static_df = spark.read.schema(schemaName).json(fileName)

streaming_df = spark.readStream(....)

new_reference_data = update_reference_df(streaming_df, static_df)

```
def update_reference_df(df, static_df):
    query: StreamingQuery = df \
        .writeStream \
        .outputMode("append") \
        .foreachBatch(lambda batch_df, batchId: update_static_df(batch_df, static_df)) \
        .start()
 return query

def update_static_df(batch_df, static_df):
    df1: DataFrame = static_df.union(batch_df.join(static_df,
                                             (batch_df.SITE == static_df.SITE)
                                             "left_anti"))

return df1
```

I want to know how will the static_df get refreshed with the new values from the data processed via foreachBatch. As I know foreachBatch returns nothing (VOID). I need to use the new values from static_df in further processing. Appreciate for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make `static_df` a global variable.

Let's use your example:

```
static_df = spark.read.schema(schemaName).json(fileName)

streaming_df = spark.readStream(....)

# No need to define a function here
query = StreamingQuery = df \
    .writeStream \
    .outputMode("append") \
    .foreachBatch(update_static_df) \
    .start()

def update_static_df(batch_df, static_df):
    global static_df
    static_df = static_df.union(batch_df.join(static_df,
                                             (batch_df.SITE == static_df.SITE)
                                             "left_anti"))


# do whatever you want for static_df
```